# Create and e-mail a table

Tags: powershell, smtp

I would like to be able to create a table and then e-mail that table to myself and I am having a lot of trouble making it work. I believe that my table is correct but I need someone who has done this before to look over this.

```
$PrintTest = "PASSED"
$InternetTest1 = "PASSED"
$InternetTest2 = "PASSED"
$SkypeServiceStatus = "PASSED"
$SharePointServiceStatus = "PASSED"

$table = New-Object system.Data.DataTable “Daily Morning Health Checks”

$col0 = New-Object system.Data.DataColumn TEST,([string])

$col1 = "Printing"
$col2 = "Google"
$col3 = "MSN"
$col4 = "Skype"
$col5 = "Intranet"

$table.columns.add($col1)
$table.columns.add($col2)
$table.columns.add($col3)
$table.columns.add($col4)
$table.columns.add($col5)

$row0 = $table.NewRow();$row = "TEST and RESULTS";
$row1 = $table.NewRow();$row = $PrintTest;$row = $InternetTest1;$row = $InternetTest2;$row = $SkypeServiceStatus;$row = $SharePointServiceStatus
$table| Format-Table -AutoSize


<#****Test E-Mail****#>
$To = "jsmith@example.com"
$From = "IT@example.com"
$Subject = "Daily Health Check"
$SMTPServer = "MY_Server"
$Body = $Table
$Port = "25"

Send-MailMessage -To $To -Cc $CarbonCopy -From $From -Subject $Subject -SmtpServer $SMTPServer -Body $Body -Port $Port
```

Comment: In what way is it not working?

Comment: Rather than creating a `DataTable`, could you just make a pscustomobject and then pipe through `ConvertTo-Html`?

Comment: I agree with @BenH, there are some quite good [tutoral videos on youtube](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=convertTo-Html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a much simpler method. I do however appreciate the vigor of the previous poster.

$HTML1 = " Daily Health Checks **Application****Status** Printing$PrintTest Internet$InternetTest1 Conference PC: $Server1 $ServerTest1 Conference PC: $Server2$ServerTest2  Conference PC: $Server3$ServerTest3

Comment: Glad you found a simple solution. I will have to mess around with your method to see what it can do. Do you know if you can format the font, foreground and background colors and if it will handle up to 10 tables? I am having to highlight things that are incorrect with colors and making it easy to read

Answer (score 1):

This is going to be difficult to read but I know it like the back of my hand because I had developed an HTML email with PS after querying MS SQL and AD for info. Built the logic and then looped over the data to build the HTML Tables injecting all the HTML formatting

All tables I did were using an ArrayList. It was complicated to get everything to work and then have the HTML work with Outlook. Works like a charm now though.

Please let me know if you have a question and might be considering using HTML for the tables.

EDIT: Some of this won't pertain to what you need. Just showing some of the logic and how it can be done. Wasn't sure what to include and exclude without revealing company info.

```
[string]$HTML_Head = "
<head>
    <style>
        th.h1 {font-size: 20px; background-color: #709faf; font-family: Arial Bold, Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: bold; text-align: center; border: solid; border-width: 1px}
        th.h2 {font-size: 15px; font-family: Arial Bold, Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: bold; text-align: center}
        th.s1 {font-size: 13px; background-color: #f0f5f7; font-family: Arial Bold, Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: bold; padding: 2px 4px 2px 4px}
        td.s1 {vertical-align: top}
        td.s2v1 {font-size: 12px; background-color: #a9c5cf; font-family: Arial Bold, Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: bold; text-align: center; padding: 2px 4px 2px 4px}
        td.s2v2 {font-size: 12px; background-color: #d9e8ee; font-family: Arial Bold, Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: bold; text-align: center; padding: 2px 4px 2px 4px}
        table.s1 {font-size: 12px; background-color: #b7cfd7; border: solid; border-width: 2px}
        table.s2 {font-size: 12px; background-color: #709faf; border: solid; border-width: 1px; width: 100%}
    </style>
</head>"

[string]$HTML_Body = "
<body>
    <table class='s1'>
        <tr>
            <th class='h1' colspan='3'>Table Name</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class='s1'>
                $Table_1
            </td>
            <td class='s1'>
                $Table_2
            <br>
                $Table_3
            </td>
            <td class='s1'>
                $Table_4
            </td> 
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>"

Function Create-Table([string]$Input_Title, [string]$Input_Colspan, [System.Collections.ArrayList]$Input_Headers, `
        [System.Collections.ArrayList]$Input_Data, [string]$Input_Primary_Condition, [string]$Input_Secondary_Condition, [int]$Input_Logic_1, [string]$Input_Logic_2, `
        [string]$Input_Change_Type, [string]$Input_Change_Logic) {

    [string]$Table_Colspan = "'" + $Input_Colspan + "'"
    [string]$Title = $Input_Title
    [string]$Condition_1 = $Input_Primary_Condition
    [string]$Condition_2 = $Input_Secondary_Condition
    [int]$Logic_1 = $Input_Logic_1
    [string]$Logic_2 = $Input_Logic_2
    [System.Collections.ArrayList]$Headers = $Input_Headers
    [string]$Table_Style_Counter = "1"
    [string]$Table_Title = "
        <tr class='s1'>
            <th class='h2' colspan=$Table_Colspan>$Title</th>
        </tr>"
    [string]$Table_Header = "`n<tr>" + ($Headers | ForEach-Object {"`n<th class='s1'>$_</th>"}) + "`n</tr>"

    If ($Input_Data) {
        [string]$Table_Data = $Input_Data | ForEach-Object {
            If ($Table_Style_Counter -eq 1) {
                $Table_Style_Version = "'s2v1'"
                $Table_Style_Counter = 2
            }
            Else {
                $Table_Style_Version = "'s2v2'"
                $Table_Style_Counter = 1
            }

            $ID = $_

            "`n<tr class='s1'>" 
            $Headers | ForEach-Object {
                $Line_Data = "`n<td class=$Table_Style_Version>" + $ID.$_ + "</td>"

                If ($Input_Change_Type -eq "1") {            
                    If ($_ -eq $Condition_1) {
                        $Line_Data = $Line_Data -replace "'>", "' style='background-color: #f4a460'>"
                    }
                    Elseif ($_ -eq $Condition_2) {
                        $Line_Data = $Line_Data -replace "'>", "' style='background-color: #ffff99'>"
                    }                
                    Else {
                        $Line_Data = $Line_Data
                    }

                    If ($_ -eq "Days") {
                        If (($ID.Days -as [int]) -ge 20) {
                            $Line_Data -replace "'>", "' style='background-color: #e74c3c'>"
                        }
                        ElseIf (($ID.Days -as [int]) -ge 10) {
                            $Line_Data -replace "'>", "' style='background-color: #f1948a'>"
                        }
                        Else {
                            $Line_Data
                        }
                    }
                    Else {
                        $Line_Data
                    }
                }
                ElseIf ($Input_Change_Type -eq "2") {
                    If ($_ -eq $Logic_2) {
                        If ($ID.$_ -gt $Logic_1) {
                            $Line_Data = $Line_Data -replace "'>", "' style='background-color: #f4a460'>"
                        }
                        Else {
                            $Line_Data = $Line_Data
                        }
                    }
                    Else {
                        $Line_Data = $Line_Data
                    }

                    If ($_ -eq "Change") {                    
                        If (($ID.Change -as [int]) -gt 0) {
                            $Line_Data -replace "'>", "' style='background-color: #f4a460'>"
                        }
                        ElseIf (($ID.Change -as [int]) -lt 0) {
                            $Line_Data -replace "'>", "' style='background-color: #98fb98'>"
                        }
                        Else {
                            $Line_Data
                        }
                    }
                    Else {
                        $Line_Data
                    }
                }
            }

            "`n</tr>"
        }
    }
    else {
        [string]$Column_Count = "'" + $Headers.Count + "'"
        [string]$Table_Data = "<td class='s2v1' style='background-color: #98fb98' colspan=$Column_Count>No Errors</td>"
    }

    Return "<table class='s2'>
                $Table_Title
                $Table_Header
                $Table_Data
            </table>"
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. you are clearly a gifted powershell writer.